# How can I fix this flask routing problem in my app?

Tags: python, html, web, flask, routes

I am setting up an app which is making a request to an API from a word input from the user on page A, then getting some data through a JSON output from the API and then displaying it on page B.

The problem is that I try to set up a route name "/bienvenue1" that Flask does not want, I get:
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

only works fine with "/" as a route. But then, I don't manage to make my second post method page "/page ajoutée" because the url is still "/" though the render_template worked well...If I try to use the text input box on the bienvenue1.html page, it still tries to operate my def text_box() function and I get: 
werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap..newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'text'

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_user import login_required, UserManager, UserMixin, SQLAlchemyAdapter
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
import requests 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/homee')
def index():
    return render_template("homee.html")

@app.route('/profile')
@login_required
def profile():
    return '<h1>This is the protected profile page!'

@app.route('/bienvenue1', methods=['POST'])
def text_box():
    text = request.form['text']
    # call the api
    API_KEY = "blablabla"
    url= "blablablabla".format(text)+API_KEY
    response = requests.get(url)
    result=response.json()
    result_processed=result['articles'][0:4]
    u=[]
    v=[]
    x=[]
    for i in result_processed:
        u.append(i['url'])
        v.append(i['urlToImage'])
        x.append(i['description'])
    return render_template("bienvenue1.html",lienimage0=v[0],lienimage1=v[1],lienimage2=v[2],message1=u[0],message2=u[1],message3=u[2],description0=x[0],description1=x[1],description2=x[2])

@app.route('/mesarticles')
def mesarticles():
    return render_template("mesarticlesenregistres.html")

@app.route('/pageajoutee', methods=['POST'])
def text_box1():
    text1 = request.form['text1']
    url=Two(id=1,url1='text1')
    db.session.add(url)
    db.session.commit()
    return 'article ajouté à votre liste'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I've been turning in circles since days with that...If anyone could help would be great.

Thanks a lot

Paul

Comment: Hi PGP, would you mind sharing also how you are making the requests and what is the expected outcome? That would help !

Comment: Hi calestini, thx for helping

So, this code is taking the text input from a text box (on the /homee page) 
def text_box():
    text = request.form['text']
It is sent to an API through the url request:
response = requests.get(url)
    result=response.json()
then I process this result and send it to the bienvenue1.html template. The processed result (JSON file from the API, gives me some images and url links that I put in the bienvenue1.html template)
On this bienvenue1.html  page is another text box I want to use to save the input:
def text_box1():
    text1 = request.form['text1']

Comment: Sorry @PGP I meant how you are making the post requests from your html. Would you mind sharing the code or a sample code of how you are creating your forms and submitting it? The `html` code would help in the resolution.

Comment: ah okay! @calestini :)
The first one like that:
<form action="." method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="text">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">OK</button>
</form>

The second one this way:
<form action="." method="POST">
                  <input type="text" name="text1">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">OK</button>
</form>

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I will try to break down to pieces what I understood from the question.

#### Route `/bienvenue1` not working when you try to access it

The reason here is simply that when you try to access it you need a `GET` request and at the moment you are only accepting a `POST` request in that route. If you want both the `GET` and `POST` you should pass that to methods. Also note that because you are receiving both methods you might want to make sure to act differently depending whether you are loading the page or submitting the form.

```py
from flask import url_for, redirect, request
@app.route('/bienvenue1', methods=('GET','POST'))
def text_box():
    if request.method == 'POST':
         ## deal with post

    ## deal with get

   ...
```

#### Not able to submit forms.

From what you have shared in your comment, below if the form you are trying to submit:

```html
<form action="." method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="text">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
         OK</button>
</form>
```

However you are setting your `action` to `.`. Here you should write the link where the form is supposed to be sent to, or in a flask-friendly way:

```html
<form action="{{url_for('text_box')}}" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="text">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
         OK</button>
</form>
```

You can also try passing whatever `url` is supposed to be at the end, at least for testing purposes. So essentially you need to submit the form to the right `action` and that will take care to render the other page.

#### Redirect from one route to another after a post

If you want to redirect, say, from `/bienvenue1` to `/mesarticles` after a form is submitted, you just need to add that inside `text_box()` function:

```py
from flask import url_for, redirect, request

@app.route('/bienvenue1', methods=('GET','POST'))
def text_box():
    if request.method == 'POST':
         ## deal with post (get form, API, etc)
         return redirect(url_for('mesarticles'))
    ## deal with get
```

The same applies for `text_box1()`.

**PS** If you could edit your question to add (1) what is the exact expectation and add (2) your `html` code, that would help